# getting stringXmlContent and write then saved in to .xml file stored in sdcard in android how can possible?

Tags: android, sd-card, xmlpullparser

I am implementing read and write xml in resource folder. Reading is ok, how can I modify this xml file save as sdcard:

```
EditText myXmlContent = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_xml);
String stringXmlContent;
try {
    stringXmlContent = getEventsFromAnXML(this);
    myXmlContent.setText(stringXmlContent);
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am getting stringXmlContent. How can stringXmlContent be converted in to an xml file saved in sdcard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you don't use XMLParse or DOM